# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'DateOffset'

Tags: python, datetime

I have referred previous links in stackoverflow but still not getting the exact answer. I am using Colab notebook.
My df.tail() looks like this:

df.tail()

[image]

I want to create next empty 24 rows for 24 months for prediction
My code:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset

future_dates = [df.index[-1] + DateOffset(months = x) for x in range (0,24)]
```

It gives me error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'DateOffset'.

Comment: Please include a sample initialized dataframe and the full traceback of the error from the running example code you post.

Comment: What type do you expect `df.index[-1]` to be?

Comment: tdelaney , this is a Gold price monthly data from 1979 to May 2021.  Now I want to predict price for next 24 months for which I am  coding "future_dates = [df.index[-1] + DateOffset(months = x) for x in range (0,24)]"
. I have calculated seasonal first difference using  - df['Sesonal first difference'] = df['Price'] - df['Price'].shift(12)

Comment: @JohnGordon - I'm not sure how helpful that comment is. Its likely a RangeIndex object and `df.index[-1]` is just the last valid index value -and hence that's what's causing the problem. But isn't it just better to explain that?

Comment: "I want to create next empty 24 rows for 24 months for prediction" Did you mean that you wanted to add 24 lines to your dataframe? Or there is a list of type(DateOffset) or something else?

Comment: @Sabrin - That's a bunch of stuff I don't care about. I asked you simply to post a working program. Its likely you are using the df.index value incorrectly but we don't know because we don't know how you setup the dataframe. Don't expect us to write the code to test for you!

Comment: @John Gordon, type pf df.index[-1] is  int and its value is 508.

Comment: That last row of the dataset is `df.iloc[-1]`. You use .iloc for integer indexing. You may want `df.iloc[-1]["Date"] + DateOffset...`

Comment: @Antonio Margaretti, Yes to the existing dataframe of 509 rows, I want to add 24 more rows with dates which I will later use for predicting price using SARIMAX model .

Comment: @tdelaney, Thanks a lot. It Worked.  You can add this as answer.

Comment: @Sabrin So in that way you don't append lines like that(using last indexes or something). So if name of your data frame is future_dates, you can simply do future_dates = future_dates.append(data, ignore_idex=True) where data is your dict-like data with keys like columns of dataframes and values are values. This was to add single row. To add multiple data may be a list of dicts with same rules as above

Answer (score 1):

`df.index` is the indexer for the dataframe, not the dataframe itself. The default indexer for a dataframe is a pandas `RangeIndex` object. When you index this object, it returns the integer index that your index resolves to. Negative indexes count from the end, so `[-1]` is the final valid index of the dataframe. For a dataframe of 509 rows, 508 is the last valid index.

Instead, you can use the [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) method to get rows by integer index. As with everything pandas, iloc has its complications (see the docs) but you can do

```
future_dates = [df.iloc[-1]["Date"] + DateOffset(months = x) for x in range (0,24)]
```